# How do I import a JKS where I do not have the private key

Tags: jwt, certificates, crypto

The public cert is issued by the claims provider.
It is for custom apex JWT verification. I get an error when uploading:

> "Error: No certificate was imported because the keystore file doesn't contain a PrivateKey entry. Check the file and try again."

This works if I load the public key manually:

```
Blob publicKey = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('MIIBCg......');

//returns true    
System.debug(Crypto.verify('RSA-SHA256', Blob.valueOf(payload), bsignature, publicKey));
```

I want to be able to use this way instead:

```
Crypto.verify('RSA-SHA256', Blob.valueOf(payload), bsignature, '<cert name>'))
```

Folloing is the coomand to create the keystore:

```
keytool -importcert -file cert.cer -keystore cert.jks -alias stgcert -storetype jks
```

Comment: You can't: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60608/saml-sso-unable-to-import-certificate-via-java-keystore-file-jks. You'll just have to Deal With It (tm) by not using Certificates and Keys for your public key.

Comment: What is "(tm)" ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark_symbol

Comment: @identigral, Thanks for the confirmation. Salesforce should implement trustedcertentry jks file for upload.

Comment: @K A Agreed, this would be useful. You can create an idea on [Idea Exchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/), you'll have our vote.

Comment: @identigral I have created an idea in exchange. Thanks!

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000KtClmUAF/allow-jks-to-be-uploaded-with-trustedcertentry

Comment: @K A Excellent, thank you. Upvoted it.